# How can I perform the same statement if it passes one or more if statements?

Tags: python, simplify

I want to perform the same task if it passes a chain of if-elif statements.

Presented below is an example of what I am trying to achieve. The program runs bug free, but I was wondering if there was a simpler method to assign `continue_program` to `Yes` without typing it out multiple times if it meets one of the conditions.

```
word_form = "A string!"
continue_program = "No"

number = 2

if number == 1:
    word_form = "one"
    continue_program = "Yes"
elif number == 2:
    word_form = "two"
    continue_program = "Yes"
elif number == 3:
    word_form = "three"
    continue_program = "Yes"
```

Comment: You can say `continue_program = number in (1,2,3)`, but I'm not convinced it's better than what you have now.

Comment: Did you consider inverting the logic? Instead of thinking of the rule that tells you when `continue_program` should be `True`, think of the rule that tells you when it should be `False`. Then you should be able to see a simple way to attach that to the rest of the code.

Comment: If I were doing it, I'd have those `word_form` things in a dictionary, and do `if number in word_forms:` / `word_form = word_forms[number]` / `continue_program = True`.

Comment: I would set the flag to True before the `if` statement, and if it gets to an `else` clause, that means it never matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a little *too* concise:

```
d = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"}

continue_program = bool(word_form := d.get(number, "")))
```

Look up `number` in `d`, which will result in either the desired string or the empty string. As a side effect, assign that string to `word_form`. The boolean value of that string is further assigned to `continue_program`.

Some examples; first, `number == 6`:

```
>>> bool(word_form := d.get(6, ""))
False
>>> word_form
''
```

Now, `number == 1`:

```
>>> bool(word_form := d.get(1, ""))
True
>>> word_form
'one'
```

Update: use a conditional expression to map `True`/`False` to `"Yes"/"No"`"

```
continue_program = "Yes" if (word_form := d.get(number, "")) else "No"
```

---

Pre-3.8,

```
word_form = d.get(number, "")
continue_program = "Yes" if word_form else "No"
```

Comment: The only caveat is if you're stuck using Python earlier than 3.8 like me, the walrus operator `:=` is not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your if blocks and check at the end if the "word_form" has length, then you can assign coninue_program to True, something like:

```
word_form = ""
continue_program = False

number = 2

if number == 1:
    word_form = "one"
elif number == 2:
    word_form = "two"
elif number == 3:
    word_form = "three"

if len(word_form) > 0:
   continue_program = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i can think of two solution using switch-case like approach:

1)

```
def num(arg):
switcher = {
    1:True,
    2:True,
    3:True,
    4:False
}
return switcher.get(arg, False)
```

2. 

```
def func1():
    print("hi func1")
def func2():
    print("hi func2")
def default():
    print("hi default")
def num2(arg):
    switcher = {
        1:func1,
        2:func2,
    }
    return switcher.get(arg, default)

num2(1)()
print("space")
num2(3)()
```

which will print like this:

```
hi func1
space
hi default
```

you can learn more about this from here [switch-case](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-case-in-python-replacement/)